# MUI DATATABLE lazy loading option is not there

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am trying to implement a table with MUI DATATABLE. I want to display records as we scroll vertically instead of pagination.If we provide pagination then user has to click next page to see next records . So i want to implement a table like lazy loading. I have seen that there is no option in the MUI DATATABLE to load records as we scroll. Is there any option to load records lazily.

Comment: What you describe is called *infinite loading*. Does this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/52xz76v5wn) demonstrate what you want?

Comment: @Naresh did you implemented lazy loading in this